# Javascript - grab value inside of an object nested within an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, ecmascript-6

I am trying to grab a value of a key inside of an object in an array which itself is an object in an array.
Here is what it looks like:

```
var books = [
        {
            "title": "title1",
            "author": "author1",
            "users": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "Isidro"
                },
                {
                    "id": 4,
                    "name": "Jose Miguel"
                },
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "name": "Trinidad"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "title": "title2",
            "author": "author2",
            "users": [
                {
                    "id": 4,
                    "name": "Jose Miguel"
                },
                {
                    "id": 5,
                    "name": "Beatriz"
                },
                {
                    "id": 6,
                    "name": "Rosario"
                }
            ]
        },
```

What I am trying to do, 2 things: 
First:
when I click on a user name in the HTML, I want to match the name clicked with the same user name in all the objects it is present in.
Second:
display the title of the books this user name is present in.
For example: when I click on Jose Miguel I want to see the 2 books he has read.

At the moment I have this:

```
var btnUser = document.querySelectorAll(".individualUsers");
        for (var i = 0; i < btnUser.length; i++) {
          btnUser[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
            var clickedUser = this.innerText
            var userBooks = books
              .filter(x => x.users.name.indexOf(clickedUser) > -1)
              .map(x => ` <li>${x.title}</li> <li>${x.author}</li>`);

          console.log(clickedUser);
          });
        }
```

My problem is `x.users.name.indexOf(clickedUser)`is not accessing the user name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to search inside the `users` array as well, one neat way is to do so with `Array.some` that return **true** if some of the conditional is true.

```js
const books = [{
    "title": "title1",
    "author": "author1",
    "users": [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Isidro"
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Jose Miguel"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Trinidad"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "title2",
    "author": "author2",
    "users": [{
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Jose Miguel"
      },
      {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "Beatriz"
      },
      {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "Rosario"
      }
    ]
  }
];

const clickedUser = 'Jose Miguel';

var userBooks = books
  .filter(x => x.users.some(user => user.name.indexOf(clickedUser) > -1));

console.log(userBooks);
```